# Why qemu-system-x86 takes 100% of my CPU?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, openstack, qemu, openstack-autopilot

I've changed my old laptop with a new one but I don't understand why using on both virt-manager the `qemu-system-x86` on new one takes 100% of CPU when run a vm, while on old one not.

The command:

**`lscpu`**

has this output:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 69
Stepping:              1
CPU MHz:               754.000
BogoMIPS:              5187.74
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

While in my old PC it just uses 15%-30% of the CPU. I've also actived the kvm from the BIOS but nothing changes: it continues to use 100%.

The top command gives me:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
3410 libvirt+  20   0 3641892 902428  10332 S 101,4 11,2   1:03.36 qemu-system-x86
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: This indicates that you have some VM running, although I don't know why it would be starting automatically at startup. Running `ps aux | grep qemu-system-x86` will give you the full arguments for the process.

Comment: the result of that command is that http://paste.ubuntu.com/9625324/

Comment: There's a VM named `CanonicalDistibution` running, with a storage file at `/home/d4rkn3t/VStorage/CanonicalDistibution.img`. You can install the `virt-manager` to get a GUI (Virtual Machine Manager) so that you can stop or delete the VM.

Comment: VM already run on virtual-manager. I don't understand why in my old PC I never saw virt-manager token 100% of ram, while in new one the result is that?

Comment: Don't know about that. Is it possible you used some special ISO in installing Ubuntu in the new laptop?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04Lts 64bit that's it

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to make sure you use the proper accelaration for qemu?
Such as:

```
qemu-system-x86_64  -machine accel=kvm [...]
```

This switch could make your computer use hardware virtualization
(cpu usage drops to negligible then)

Answer (score -9):

I've resolved that modify an option on BIOS,after that now CPU uses just 20%.

Comment: hi, can you tell us what did you modify on bios?

Comment: What option was that?...